# Can I use the Rename utility to simplify this script that uses Find and Mv?

Tags: shell-script, rename

I use a script to automatically rename files according to a particular order:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

pages=($(sed -n '/page_order/,/^$/ p' _config.yml | tail -n +2 | sed 's/ - //'))
npages=${#pages}
for ((i=1; i<=$npages; i++)); do
  page=${pages[$i]}
  old=${(f)$(gfind . -iregex ".*/.*${page}.md")[1]}
  pagenumber=$(printf '%0*d\n' ${#npages} $i)
  new="${pagenumber}-${page}.md"
  mv -i $old $new
done
```

where `_config.yml` has the entry

```
page_order:
 - foo
 - bar
 - baz
```

so that the files `foo.md bar.md baz.md` will be automatically renamed to `1-foo.md 2-bar.m 3-baz.md`.

Is there a way to simplify this process using the `rename` utility? I'm using Mac OS X 10.10.

(For a pure zsh solution, see [Can I use Zsh's built-in wildcard matching to replace the use of `find` here?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/232367/can-i-use-zshs-built-in-wildcard-matching-to-replace-the-use-of-find-here))

Comment: Which `rename`? The one that uses Perl?

Comment: I don't think so. You have to parse the file for the file order, then give that argument to a command. `rename` really excels in modifying strings with regular expressions (I assume you are talking about the more powerful "perl" rename). If you have to supply it with this numerical argument, you might as well use `mv`. If you were to use `rename`, you'd just replace the `mv` line with a `rename`-based command.

Comment: `find` has no primary called `iregex`. If you use vendor specific software, it would help if you mention which nonstandard programs you are using.

Comment: @schily it does in the version I have. At the bottom of the manpage it says "BSD September 28, 2011". It's also a primary in the GNU version.

Comment: @muru yes it's the Perl rename

Comment: Well, the problem with the way gfind defines -regex is that it is incompatible to the usual behavior where people expect only a path name component to match unless there is an additional "path" or "p" in the primary name. A typical UNIX (SunOS/HP-UX/AIX) does not support it at all.

Comment: @schily it's the same in the BSD version that comes with OS X. I can't say I like it, but it's there. Then again, do I even need to use `find` at all here? I feel like this is something I could accomplish with globbing in Zsh.

Comment: I usually don't use zsh, so I cannot tell but it may be that if zsh implements something similar to ksh93s `globstar`, it should work without `find`. On the other side, the recent Bourne Shell has a builtin `find` command based on libfind. In the future, libfind will get a `-call` interface that allows it to call back shell code. Then probably libfind seems to be the most interesting way to implement tree traversal in the shell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can get your list of *files* as a set of arguments to Perl's `rename` this can be done quite easily:

```
rename 'no warnings; $a++; s!^(.*/)?(.*)!$1$a-$2!' "$@"
```

Variables `$a` and `$b` are predeclared globals in Perl, so although the entire expression should be considered to be within a loop (and scoped accordingly), they will keep their values throughout the lifetime of the execution. The substitution itself inserts the current value of `$a` as part of the filename, allowing that the argument could also be a pathname. (We split the argument into `dirname` and `basename`, resulting in components $1 and $2.)

The `no warnings` pragma stops the substitution complaining about the missing pathname component. This wouldn't usually be required but I think the `rename` command has extra warnings enabled.

Add `-n` to dry-run, or `-v` for action with confirmation.

Alternatively, you could use a snippet of perl to take the parameters you've got and apply them to a set of files. But by the time you've done that you might as well parse the YAML in Perl too.

Comment: "by the time you've done that you might as well parse the YAML in Perl too". Good point. I'm not actually a Perl user so maybe it's not worth bothering with. My script works just fine as it is