# Can I use Zsh's built-in wildcard matching to replace the use of `find` here?

Tags: find, zsh, wildcards

*This is a follow-up to [another question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/232295/73256) I posted*

I use a script to automatically rename files according to a particular order:

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

pages=($(sed -n '/page_order/,/^$/ p' _config.yml | tail -n +2 | sed 's/ - //'))
npages=${#pages}
for ((i=1; i<=$npages; i++)); do
  page=${pages[$i]}
  old=${(f)$(gfind . -iregex ".*/.*${page}.md")[1]}  # <- the line I hope to replace
  pagenumber=$(printf '%0*d\n' ${#npages} $i)
  new="${pagenumber}-${page}.md"
  mv -i $old $new
done
```

where `_config.yml` has the entry

```
page_order:
 - foo
 - bar
 - baz
```

so that the files `foo.md bar.md baz.md` will be automatically renamed to `1-foo.md 2-bar.m 3-baz.md`.

Is there a way to skip `find` entirely and just use Zsh globbing? I'm using Zsh 5.1 on Mac OS 10.10 if that helps at all; note that the `-iregex` primary in the BSD version of `find` that comes with OS X isn't standard.

Comment: Do you have multiple files matching `foo`, `bar` etc e.g. `afoo.md`, `bfoo.md`, `abar.md`, `bbar.md` etc that should be renamed to `1-afoo.md`, `1-bfoo.md`, `2-abar.md`, `2-bbar.md` etc ?

Comment: @don_crissti I shouldn't, but it's always a possibility. The current script just cheats by taking the first match, which isn't optimal.

Comment: I would be interested, why people believe that it may be a good idea to avoid `find`. Could you explain what you expect from such a solution and why you prefer to avoid find?

Comment: @schily I'm just looking to learn other tools

Comment: Ok, I believe that `find` implements a very powerful syntax that is well known by many people. This is why I created libfind. The question thus is why do people like to learn another method even though there is libfind.

Comment: @schily - OP is using one `find` per _$page_ which means with e.g. 200 _pages_ the script would run `find` 200 times so I'd say it's a good idea to avoid using `find` like that, especially when this can be done `zsh`-only.

Comment: As mentioned, my impression is still that find is the more general solution. 200 find calls are not a real problem and in a recent Bourne Shell, find is even a builtin command. BTW: I was interested whether the find syntax or method could be enhanced to do tings better.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could do this with `zsh` alone (i.e. with `zmv`):

```
autoload zmv
for name ($pages)
zmv -Qn "(**/)(*${name}.md)(.N)" "\${1}${pages[(i)${name}]}-\${2}"
```

the `-n` stands for no execution (*dry-run*) so you'll get an output like:

```
mv -- 'some dir/deeper/gfoo.md' 'some dir/deeper/1-gfoo.md'
mv -- 'some dir/zfoo.md' 'some dir/1-zfoo.md'
mv -- afoo.md 1-afoo.md
mv -- nfoo.md 1-nfoo.md
mv -- bar.md 2-bar.md
mv -- baz.md 3-baz.md
.........
```

if you're happy with the result remove the `-n` to actually move the files (or replace it with `-i` if you want it to run in interactive mode).

---

How it works:
`$name` is the array element and `${pages[(i)${name}]}` is the position of the element in the array, so e.g. if `pages=(foo bar baz bom top)` then:

```
for name ($pages)
printf '%s %s\n' ${pages[(i)$name]} $name
```

```
1 foo
2 bar
3 baz
4 bom
5 top
```